# FMDB Swift SQL Get Number of Rows in Table

Tags: sqlite, swift, fmdb

FMDB seems to have lots of functions to deal with columns but none for rows. All I am trying to do is find the number of rows in a table.

```
func getTableRows() {
    sharedInstance.database!.open()
    let sqlStatement = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NAMESTABLE"
    var resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery(sqlStatement, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    if (resultSet != nil) {
        let rowCount = XXXX
        NSLog("Table Rows = %i",rowCount)
    }
    sharedInstance.database!.close()
}
```

I have tried various approaches with the XXXX but no joy. Am I going about this the wrong way? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
func getTableRows() {
    sharedInstance.database!.open()
    let sqlStatement = "SELECT COUNT(field) FROM table_name"
    var resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery(sqlStatement, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    if (resultSet != nil) {
        let rowCount = XXXX
        NSLog("Table Rows = %i",rowCount)
    }
    sharedInstance.database!.close()
}
```

Comment: Surely they'd return the same number but specifying a column is more efficient.

I still don't know how to extract the number, but no joy.

I have tried:

    let rowCount = resultSet.intForColumnIndex(0)

Comment: let rowCount = resultSet.intForColumnIndex(0)
 is what I originally used but it always returns 0.

Comment: This does it but I don't understand why I need to encapsulate it in a while loop: while resultSet.next() {
            rowCount = resultSet.intForColumnIndex(0)
            NSLog("Table Rows = %d",rowCount)
        }

Comment: No need to put it in a while, if statement will do the job : 
if resultSet.next() { let rowCount = resultSet.intForColumnIndex(0) NSLog("Table Rows = %d",rowCount) }